# Hibernate, exception al hacer update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tengo una excepción al llamar un metodo update() de la clase UserService, con el objetivo de actualizar un los datos de un usuario salvados en el db.

**Clase UserService:**

```
import java.util.List;

import db.hibernate.dao.UserDao;
import models.User;

public class UserService {
    private static UserDao userDao;

    public UserService() {
        userDao = new UserDao();
    }

    public void persist(User entity) {
        userDao.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
        userDao.persist(entity);
        userDao.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    }

    public void update(User entity) {
        userDao.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
        userDao.update(entity);
        userDao.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    }

/*otros metodos*/
```

La clase viene llamada desde el controlador de la view PaneUser al hacer click en el boton "Delete":

**Clase PaneUserController:**

```
public class PaneUserController {

    private UserService userService = new UserService();

    List<User> allUsers = userService.findAll();

    public PaneUserController(PaneUser paneUser) {

        //codigo

        paneUser.addCrudListener(new CrudListener());
        initUserView();

    }

    public void initUserView() {

        theUserView.setFieldData(allUsers.get(0));
    }

    class CrudListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    //crea un user con los datos de input
            User user = theUserView.getFieldData();

            switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
            case "Search":
                // opens the searchUI

                break;
            case "New...":

                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) pUser.getLayout();
                cardLayout.show(pUser, "Pane attributeSet");

                break;
            case "Update":

                userService.update(user); // lanza el error en cuestion
                break;
            case "Delete":

                userService.delete(user.getUserID());
                break;

            }

        }
    }
```

**Clase UserDao:**

```
import models.User;

public class UserDao implements UserDaoInterface<User, String> {

    private Session currentSession;

    private Transaction currentTransaction;

    public UserDao() {
    }

    public Session openCurrentSession() {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return currentSession;
    }

    public Session openCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
        return currentSession;
    }

    public void closeCurrentSession() {
        currentSession.close();
    }

    public void closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
        currentTransaction.commit();
        currentSession.close();
    }

    private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                .addAnnotatedClass(models.User.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(models.Client.class).configure();

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return currentSession;
    }

    public void setCurrentSession(Session currentSession) {
        this.currentSession = currentSession;
    }

    public Transaction getCurrentTransaction() {
        return currentTransaction;
    }

    public void setCurrentTransaction(Transaction currentTransaction) {
        this.currentTransaction = currentTransaction;
    }

    public void persist(User entity) {
        getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    }

    public void update(User entity) {
        getCurrentSession().update(entity);
    }

    public User findById(String id) {
        User book = (User) getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
        return book;
    }

    public void delete(User entity) {
        getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> users = (List<User>) getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User order by userid").list();
        return users;
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        List<User> entityList = findAll();
        for (User entity : entityList) {
            delete(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

El StackTrace:

```
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [models.User#1]]
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [models.User#1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.wrapStaleStateException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3283)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2479)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98)
    at db.hibernate.dao.UserDao.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction(UserDao.java:38)
    at db.hibernate.service.UserService.update(UserService.java:24)
    at controllers.users.PaneUserController$CrudListener.actionPerformed(PaneUserController.java:63)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [models.User#1]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2522)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3355)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3229)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
    ... 47 more
```

Lo siento si e escrito mucho codigo, pero lo veo necesesario, cual puede ser la causa de este error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que sale es por que hay dos transacciones simultaneas modificando la misma fila de la base de datos.

La primera que mete el commit, es la que termina actualizando la tabla, y la segunda es rechazada al hacer el commit dado que estaría pisando los cambios de la transacción anterior.

Para que quede más claro, las dos transacciones parten con los mismos datos. Sería diferente si primero ocurre una transaccion completa, y luego la otra, partiendo con los datos de la transacción anterior ya comiteada.

Fijate como funcionan las estrategias de bloqueo de Hybernate (locking strategies)

Comment: Usar locking strategies resolveria mi problema?

Comment: Siempre se una locking strategy, el tema es cual te conviene más. Por eso te decia que leas sobre el tema. Lo normal sería que uses esta estrategia optimista, atrapes esta excepción y obligues al usuario a rehacer la actualización pero sobre los datos actualizados de la transacción comiteada.

Comment: El usuario tendría que rehacer la actualización en que modo? tendria que aplastar 2 veces el button que lanza la funcion de update?

Comment: No se cuales son los pasos que seguis para que salte el error, pero este error se te tiene que estar dando ante una segunda actualización de los mismos datos (update o delete). Suponiendo que esto realmente es así, tendrias que atrapar la excepción y mostrar un error "otra persona te ganó de mano, por favor fijate los dato nuevos y si todavía querés hacer la transacción hacela de nuevo." Por otro lado, si esto te pasa y no hay dos personas trabajando sobre los mismos datos, entonces revisá como estas abriendo y cerrando transacciones.

Comment: Algo que vi recien es que openCurrentSession() abre sesiones nuevas, no usa una existente. Fijate que eso no esté abriendo una puerta a que el mismo usuario modifique dos datos de la misma entidad en sesiones diferentes creando el escenario descripto mas arriba.

Comment: A este paso creo que usare solo JDBC para el back-end. Gracias de todos modos por tu ayuda.